# What is the probability of choosing two cards of the same value?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we draw two cards from a well-shuffled standard deck of 52 cards without replacement. Let A be the event that the two cards drawn have the same value (e.g. both 7s). Let B be the event that the two cards drawn are both face cards (e.g. Q and K).

a) What is the probability of event A given event B , $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ ?

b) What is the probability of event B given event A , $\mathsf P(B\mid A)$ ?

c) Are events A and B independent?

*NOTE* This is a homework problem for school. I would not like the answer, but instead would like some guidance towards the solution. I do know the formula for $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ is $\mathsf P(A \cap B)/\mathsf P(B)$.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack exchange what are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: So I have that P(A) = 3/57 and P(B) = 11/221 but can't seem to find a mathematical way of calculating P(A and B)... I logically thought of it this way. If you already have that the two cards that are of face value, the probability of those two cards being of the same value is (3/11) since for any first card that was chosen (of the 12 face-valued cards) there are 3 others of the same value left (of the 11 remaining cards).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have the formula 
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$$

and you pretty much only need to fill in the values.

The probability of drawing one specific card(i.e. 7 of hearts) out of 52 cards is $$\frac{1}{52}$$
The probability of drawing any 7 is $$\frac{4}{52}$$ since there are four 7s in the deck.
So, what's the probability of first drawing one 7 then another? The probability of getting the first one is as above 4/52, but the probability of drawing a second one is $$\frac{4-1}{52-1} = \frac{3}{51}$$ since the deck now consists of 51 cards of which three are 7.
I think this will help getting you started.

For the next part, having two events A and B, the probability of them both happening is P(A)*P(B) (if A and B are independent) and the probability of either of them happening is P(A) + P(B) (if the events are mutually exclusive, otherwise you need to subtract the possibility of them both happening).

Answer (score 0):

You have the right formula, so you just need hints to evaluate the probabilities.

The *sample space* is of drawing $2$ from $52$ cards.

Event $A$ is that both cards are the same value; there are $13$ values and $4$ suits of each value, so $\mathsf P(A)$ is...

Face cards are J,Q,K,A, so there are $16$ of these in the deck.   Event $B$ is that any $2$ from these $16$ are drawn.   That tells you $\mathsf P(B)$ is....

[Note: some don't count ace as face; if so there would only be $12$ faces cards and adjust other number accordingly.]

Event $A\cap B$ is that you draw two *face* cards of the same value.   That is: there are $4$ values and $4$ suits for each value to select.   Hence $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ is....

Now use your definitions.

Comment: Minor concern, but aren't there just 3 face cards, J, Q, K

Comment: So what I'm getting is that P(A) = 3/51, P(B) = 11/221 & P(A\cap B) = 36/2652....

Comment: Yes.  (and the last simplifies to $3/221$.)